# How do I assign an id to a session window in Apache Flink?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

How do I assign an id to a session window in Apache Flink?

Ultimately I want to enrich events with a session window id one-by-one while the session windows is open (I don't want to wait until the window closes before emitting the enriched events).

I tried to do this with an AggregateFunction, however I don't think merge() works as I expect. It seems to be for merging windows and not panes (trigger firings). It seems to be never called in my pipeline. It seems therefore that there is no shared state between triggers!

The session window id will be the timestamp of the first event to fall into the window (due to non-guaranteed ordering that may mean some events with could potentially fall into the same session window with an earlier timestamp - I'm ok with this).

```
public class FooSessionState {

  private Long sessionCreationTime;

  private FooMatch lastMatch;
}

/**
 * Aggregator that assigns session ids to elements of a session window
 */
public class SessionIdAssigner implements
    AggregateFunction<FooMatch, FooSessionState, FooSessionEvent> {

  static final long serialVersionUID = 0L;

  @Override
  public FooSessionState createAccumulator() {
    return new FooSessionState();
  }

  @Override
  public FooSessionState add(FooMatch value, FooSessionState sessionState) {
    if (sessionState.getSessionCreationTime() == null) {
      sessionState.setSessionCreationTime(value.getReport().getTimestamp());
    }
    sessionState.setLastMatch(value);
    return sessionState;
  }

  @Override
  public FooSessionEvent getResult(FooSessionState accumulator) {
    FooSessionEvent sessionEvent = new FooSessionEvent();
    sessionEvent.setFooMatch(accumulator.getLastMatch());
    sessionEvent.setSessionCreationTime(accumulator.getSessionCreationTime());
    return sessionEvent;

  }

  @Override
  public FooSessionState merge(FooSessionState a, FooSessionState b) {

    if ( a.getSessionCreationTime() != null) {
      b.setSessionCreationTime(a.getSessionCreationTime());
    }

    return b;
  }
}
```

My plan was to use it as follows:

```
stream.keyBy(new FooMatchKeySelector())
    .window(EventTimeSessionWindows.withGap(Time.milliseconds(config.getFooSessionWindowTimeout())))
    .trigger(PurgingTrigger.of(CountTrigger.of(1L)))
    .aggregate(new SessionIdAssigner())
```

Answer (score 0):

I think session windows are not a good fit for what you want to achieve. They have been designed to aggregate events per session, but not to enrich every event, i.e., they compute a result and emit it when the window is closed. As you noticed, session windows work by creating a new window for every event and merging windows that overlap. This design was chosen, because events might arrive out of order. Hence it might happen, that you have two windows that are later connected by a bridging event.

I would recommend to implement the logic with a `ProcessFunction` that collects the events and sorts them on their timestamp. When a watermark is received, it emits all collected events with correct session IDs. Hence, you keep only the events between two watermarks in state. In addition to those events, you need to keep the timestamp of the last emitted event and the last emitted session ID to perform correct sessionization.